# Passing get paramter to controller

Tags: scala, playframework

I realise this is probably a simple question. I'm trying to pass a get parameter to Scala Play controller :

I'm using Play2 and reading the doc:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaActions it does not seem to be specified.

Here is my function in a controller:

```
  def sj(name: String) = Action { implicit request =>

      println("Name: "+name)
      println("Request is:"+request)
      Ok(Json.toJson(List(1,2,3)).toString());

  }
```

Route points to this controller:

```
GET     /chart/data                    controllers.ChartController.sj
```

Invoking `http://localhost:9000/chart/data?name=test`

invokes the function `sj` defined above but the println statements are not being printed to the console. How to pass the get parameter "name" to a controller function ?

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaRouting#The-routes-file-syntax `GET     /chart/data                    controllers.ChartController.sj(name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment by @Mario Galic use `GET /chart/data controllers.ChartController.sj(name)` in `routes` file.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your route:

```
GET     /chart/data/:name                    controllers.ChartController.sj(name: string)
```